# Positive definiteness of n'th power of a positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices

Let's define a real (not necessarily symmetric) matrix $A$ to be *positive definite* iff $A + A^T$ is a [symmetric positive definite matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix).

Then can we conclude that $A^2$ or in general $A^n$ is positive definite?

Comment: Do you mean a **symmetric** positive definite matrix?

Comment: No, it's asymmetric. As I know asymmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite if $A+A^T$ is positive definite.

Comment: If not necessarily symmetric (real) matrices are being described as "positive definite", it is best to give your definition of the term because [usage is not standardized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Extension_for_non_symmetric_matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-symmetric positive definite matrices, the answer is no.

For example, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
Then $A$ is positive definite (i.e. $x^TAx > 0$ for real vectors $x$), but $A^4$ is not.

Comment: Note that even using the definition given by Reza in Commenting above, $A^4$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and the symmetrized $(A^4) + (A^4)^T = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, which is only positive semi-definite.

Comment: It's not "if and only if" condition. It means to check the positive definiteness of A it's sufficient to check the positive definiteness of $A+A^T$ but it's not necessary.

Comment: As I know if $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is nonsingular, $BAB^T$ is positive definite. Hence, by considering $B=A^{1/2}$ can we deduce that $A^2$ is positive definite?

Comment: Fixed it ${}{}$

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that the matrix I had before (which would now be $A^2$) was only positive semidefinite.  At any rate, this $A^4$ is indefinite.

Comment: Thanks a lot Omnomnomnom for your help.